# what is the meaning of "ferry bound train"

Tags: phrase-meaning

https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g60763-i5-k1794318-How_safe_is_commuting_from_LaGuardia_Manhattan_via_Harlem-New_York_City_New_York.html

Take the SOUTH FERRY bound Train

what is the meaning of "**ferry bound train**"?

Comment: You're parsing it incorrectly.  "South Ferry" is one phrase, a proper name.  So the train is "South Ferry"-bound; it isn't "ferry-bound".  (Although the website should really have put a hyphen there to make it clearer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionary.com defines this usage of *bound* as:

> going or intending to go; on the way to; destined (usually followed by for): *The train is bound for Denver.*

In your instance, it means take the train **going to** SOUTH FERRY. I.e. the train will usually have its final destination specified as SOUTH FERRY.

You will sometimes see the word *bound* combined with other words such as **southbound** (going South), or hyphenated as in **London-bound** (going to London).